# MFA認証について Salesforce Authenticator再設定の方法

Tags: heroku

Salesforce Authenticator Herokuアカウントを誤って削除してしまいました。
現在 Heroku アカウントにアクセスできません。
Salesforce Authenticatorに表示されるはずの認証コードが認識されません。

再設定方法を教えてください。